# Facebook login working with only one user

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm using the js sdk and have a strange problem. When i use my fb account (owner of the fb app) the login works just fine ... but if i try to use it with different account i got:

```
"An error occurred. Please try again later."
```

Please share some thoughts and pointer ... just to know where to look for the problem.

The js login function is this if it helps:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    API = FB;

    API.init({
        appId      : '460342137362549',
        status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
        cookie     : true, 
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    API.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('facebookInitDone');

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            getUser();
            status = 'connected';
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            status = 'not_authorized';
        } else {
            status = 'not_logged_in';
        }
    });

};

service.login = function(successFunc) {

    //if there is no init done yet, no internet or delay
    if(status === '') {
        return false;
    }

    API.login(function(response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {
            getUser();

            if(successFunc) {
                successFunc();
            }
        } else {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('facebookUserLoginCanceled');
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_photos'});
};
```

Comment: Is your Facebook Application is in sandbox mode?

Answer (score 1):

This might have something to do with the application configuration in Facebook. You should make sure in the application settings in Facebook that sandbox mode is disabled. When sandbox mode is enabled, only app developers can access the application.